# Circle area function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a super basic circle area function in Python 3, but it won't work.
Here's my code:

```
//Circle Area Calculator

Area = 0

Circle_Radius = 7


def circle_area():

    return Circle_Radius ** Circle_Radius ** 3.1415926535 = Area

circle_area()

    print (Area)
```

Comment: `x ** y` takes `x` to the `y` power. So your area formula us wrong. You want either `3.1415926535 * (Circle_Radius ** 2)` or `Circle_Radius * Circle_Radius * 3.1415926535`. You might want to carefully go through a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the circle area is: r ^ 2 * pi. When you do:

```
    return Circle_Radius ** Circle_Radius ** 3.1415926535 = Area
```

you actually calculate "r ^ r ^ pi"

change to this implementation:

```
import math

def circle_area(circle_radius):
    return (circle_radius ** 2) * math.pi

area = circle_area(7)
print (area)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `circle_area()` before `Area = circle_area()`?

Comment: Also note the existence of `math.pi`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Area = 0
Circle_Radius = 7

def circle_area():
    return Circle_Radius * Circle_Radius * 3.1415926535

Area = circle_area()
print (Area)   # 153.9380400215
```

1. `**` in python is power caculation, it should be `*`
2. PS: You'd better make `Circle_Radius` be a parameter of function